# How to fix my jquery ajax function other function works but the ajax did not

Tags: php, html, jquery

---------------------------PHP CODE---------------------------:

```
    <?php

$wtype = $_POST['wtype'];

$attributes = array();

if($wtype == 'Ninja'){
    $attributes['health'] = '40-60';
    $attributes['attack'] = '60-70';
    $attributes['defense'] = '20-30';
    $attributes['speed'] = '90-100';
    $attributes['evade'] = '0.3-0.5';
}
else if($wtype == 'Samurai'){
    $attributes['health'] = '60-100';
    $attributes['attack'] = '75-80';
    $attributes['defense'] = '35-40';
    $attributes['speed'] = '60-80';
    $attributes['evade'] = '0.3-0.4';
}
else if($wtype == 'Brawler'){
    $attributes['health'] = '90-100';
    $attributes['attack'] = '65-75';
    $attributes['defense'] = '40-50';
    $attributes['speed'] = '40-65';
    $attributes['evade'] = '0.3-0.35';
}

echo json_encode($attributes);

?>
```

---------------------------HMTL CODE---------------------------:

```
 <div id="warriors">
        <form id="blue_team">
            <p>
                <label class="team">Blue Team</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="#Naruto"><img class="blue_img" src="resources/naruto.png" title="Ninja" alt="Naruto"></a>
                <a href="#Sasuke"><img class="blue_img" src="resources/sasuke.png" title="Samurai" alt="Sasuke"></a>
                <a href="#Sakura"><img class="blue_img" src="resources/sakura.png" title="Brawler" alt="Sakura"></a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Name:</label>
                    <input id="blue_name" type="text" readonly="readonly">
                <label>Type:</label>
                    <input id="blue_type" type="text" readonly="readonly">
            </p>
        </form>

    <!--Blue Dialog-->
    <div title="Warrior Name - Blue" id="blue_form" class="blue_dialog">
        <form>
            <p>
                <label>Name:</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text">
            </p>
        </form>
        <table>

        <table>
    </div>
```

---------------------------JS CODE---------------------------:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("button").button();
        $(".blue_img").click(function() {
            var blue_type = $(this).attr("title").trim();
            $.ajax({
                url: "get_attributes.php",
                type: "post",
                datatype: "json",
                data: {wtype: blue_type },
                success: function(data) {
                    var toAppend = '';
                    if(typeof data === "object"){
                        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                            var attributes = data[i];
                            toAppend += "<tr><td>"+data[i]['health']+"</td></tr>";
                            toAppend += "<tr><td>"+data[i]['attack']+"</td></tr>";
                            toAppend += "<tr><td>"+data[i]['defense']+"</td></tr>";
                            toAppend += "<tr><td>"+data[i]['speed']+"</td></tr>";
                            toAppend += "<tr><td>"+data[i]['evade']+"</td></tr>";
                        }
                        $("#blue_form table").append(toAppend);
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#blue_form #name").val($(this).attr("alt").trim());
            $("#blue_form").dialog({
                    width:250,
                    resizable:false,
                    modal:true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Done": function() {
                            $("#blue_name").val($("#blue_form #name").val().trim());
                            $("#blue_type").val(blue_type);
                            $("#blue_form").hide(400);
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please I am expecting an table of data output to #blue_form but I didn't get any. But my other functions works well. But when I see the javascript console it identifies the method post

Comment: What is Firebug or Chrome's JavaScript debugger telling you?

Comment: it gets the post value and json I think the problem is from displaying

Comment: try to put `console.log(data);` after `var toAppend = '';` and look to the console

Comment: I see the data of my json, whats wrong with this

Comment: so try to put `console.log(toAppend);` before `$("#blue_form table").append(toAppend);`

Comment: still got the same values from the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I'm not sure why you need a loop, you could just do something like

```
success: function(data) {
    var toAppend = '';
    if(typeof data === "object") {
        toAppend += "<tr><td>"+data['health']+"</td></tr>";
        toAppend += "<tr><td>"+data['attack']+"</td></tr>";
        toAppend += "<tr><td>"+data['defense']+"</td></tr>";
        toAppend += "<tr><td>"+data['speed']+"</td></tr>";
        toAppend += "<tr><td>"+data['evade']+"</td></tr>";
        $("#blue_form table").append(toAppend);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BrainedWashed can you post the json string you get back from the server?

Comment: yes but i still need to add header("Content-Type: application/json"); in my php to work perfectly

Comment: @Lokesh then you're doing something wrong... json data doesn't have to be parsed when used in the way the OP is using it. It should automatically be presented as a javascript object to the success function.

Answer (score 1):

first thing you need to under stand is that there is no effect of using post method instead of get.Post method is comparatively slow it first sends the header than data

use this code in jquery ajax block

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("button").button();
        $(".blue_img").click(function() {
            var blue_type = $(this).attr("title").trim();
            $.ajax({
                url: "get_attributes.php",
                type: "post",
                datatype: "json",
                data: {wtype: blue_type },
                success: function(data) {
                    var toAppend = '';
                    var newdata=$.parseJSON(data);//first decode json and get array

                            toAppend += "<tr><td>"+newdata['health']+"</td></tr>";
                            toAppend += "<tr><td>"+newdata['attack']+"</td></tr>";
                            toAppend += "<tr><td>"+newdata['defense']+"</td></tr>";
                            toAppend += "<tr><td>"+newdata['speed']+"</td></tr>";
                            toAppend += "<tr><td>"+newdata['evade']+"</td></tr>";

                        $("#blue_form table").append(toAppend);
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#blue_form #name").val($(this).attr("alt").trim());
            $("#blue_form").dialog({
                    width:250,
                    resizable:false,
                    modal:true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Done": function() {
                            $("#blue_name").val($("#blue_form #name").val().trim());
                            $("#blue_type").val(blue_type);
                            $("#blue_form").hide(400);
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

this code will work perfectly

//the output of jsonencode is not a object it is a encoded string

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

I just added this to my php. Thanks everyone for your help, really appreciate it. tsk just a line of code cud fix